# Could not build Objective-c Module?

Tags: objective-c, swift, module

Error like the image beyond,-swift.h not find.
[image]
This was occurred when we use cocoapods to access two framework in my app, The framework A depend framework B, But framework B can not build Objective-C module Becuase of Header B-swift.h not find，I do not know why.

Comment: Forgive my English.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve on how to ask a question.  Use of images is not encouraged.

Comment: @OmniProg  Thanks very much. But I think sometimes we should think about which is the best way to solve a problem and think the rule may be not suitable for all situation(or even not right). In this situation,I think a picture can save respondent many time to understand my situation. But I will follow the rules later. THX.

Answer (score 1):

It occurred to me suddenly. I had to spend several hours and finally found a solution. Simply install pod again in Terminal. I just opened Terminal and found my project folder and run pod install. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved this question, Because the Podspec of A not add B to it's dependency field.